# About XPath string() function

Tags: xml, xpath

The [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) spec says about the string() function:

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of
>   the node in the node-set that is first in document order.

How is that useful behavior? Wouldn't it be a better idea if the conversion returned a concatenation of the text content(s) of *all* matched nodes? Or am I missing the point here?

Comment: How is "onetwothree" better than "one"?

Comment: "onetwothree" would show you that you haven't narrowed your path down well enough but that your result is just one more predicate away. It's also better for seaching in broad strokes. Sometimes - well, usually - you just want to know whether a paragraph contains the word you're looking for. Which <span> in that paragraph the word is actually in, is often of little interest.

Comment: Put it this way, how frequently do you have to search for and extract a single value than you would for multiple values? You might get the multiple values to narrow it down a bit first, but your final goal usually leads to pulling single values. If you wanted to search within a document for a specific value, what would you prefer? `//some-parent/some-set/some-value` or `//some-parent[0]/some-set[0]/some-value[0]`. I think it all boils down to what's the most common use case.

Comment: Hm. Good point. Maybe I should offer a string() and a stringRecursive() function in my XPath dialect...